# lwpoly_from_lwlines error on PostGIS ST_ConcaveHull function call

Tags: postgresql, postgis, concave-hull

I'm getting this error on the `ST_ConcaveHull` function call and I don't know how to solve it.

This is the content of my example table (`inte1: text, geom_pol: geometry`)

| inte1 | geom_pol |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |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|
| 1 | 0103000020E610000001000000190000003838ECEB628125409FBAA2D15C6D4640E2737CB562812540E9EA54D95C6D46400B2BDEE29481254034011BBA6F6D46406627255B95812540594F54E76F6D46403BFB939896822540B08795334C6D4640E1721ACA8982254007B266273B6D4640D6FE1C2D81822540C935B5563C6D4640A19384EC7D82254019ACAFAB3B6D464037F725ED748225400F0E48C73C6D46406F58700F72822540C4F69B013C6D464003FA24A7688225400977A6793D6D4640A1453AEE65822540F07B07D63C6D464014FA890D5E8225409716F8C33D6D4640F2D7360E5B822540BB9B41413D6D46400561965F52822540217043463E6D4640B17E0657508225400A96E6A43D6D464090590CFA47822540DB16BE9A3E6D4640107F6AE643822540F50B3BDE3D6D46401616B7843A8225402D037C3C3F6D464008EFF8FE37822540DD766E943E6D4640606C4D0D3A8225400D0FFD283F6D4640A9541E59258225406E88E21F426D464003ECA10963812540BD2D4EAC5C6D4640DF73E9166281254033B807815C6D46403838ECEB628125409FBAA2D15C6D4640 |
| 1 | 0103000020E610000001000000060000002723631C0A81254029941F2E696D46407CB80AAF3C81254066E054827B6D46400B2BDEE29481254034011BBA6F6D4640E2737CB562812540E9EA54D95C6D46401862AC9432812540885231A7636D46402723631C0A81254029941F2E696D4640 |
| 1 | 0103000020E6100000010000000B00000007A01D0E098125401833A2C6666D46404A89CDC65E8125403808965E5B6D4640A12D26DA4F812540747A21C1556D46401C0A86C0438125404189C67D516D46404F91817743812540C2474488516D4640487A0C18438125406C78FB95516D4640EC528260408125400299EBF9516D46403BD1EC7D11812540018DF26D5E6D46400C97C177138125404F11B6CF5E6D4640702CF614FA8025408B44DB6E626D464007A01D0E098125401833A2C6666D4640 |
| 1 | 0103000020E6100000010000000B0000007D0E7DC523802540C418005FA26D4640D7C6C2B303812540887C58F3836D464058351F2C348125401C84463E7D6D464006E0462610812540E260725D706D4640E9FB651A038125400DCDA536726D464085C10D3505812540BF153D33736D4640FD1E0DF1A880254093C0F9937F6D4640DA87CC1B7A802540E5DC0142756D46403D642F8E6A802540D503C8A3776D46409F6AE00A4380254075C987BC886D46407D0E7DC523802540C418005FA26D4640 |
| 1 |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|
| 1 | 0103000020E6100000010000000C000000A329050C21812540380965FA226C46400CCDAD1F7D812540ED67016D1E6C4640A0F8CC4D7C8125407F49A2F31D6C4640A6570384768125400AA3DC3A1E6C46406CF892DA638125409C583BFD126C46409955DFF36881254061F0CDC2126C464005F3A7EC65812540338F7F02116C46401DD517B3678125401299FAE8106C4640EAEB05DB65812540E5A686F6106C464096DC62C8418125403A44D91BFC6B46407CF56C70E480254082AF1F8C016C4640A329050C21812540380965FA226C4640 |
| 1 | 0103000020E61000000100000005000000A9473320E5802540E197733EFF6B46409C7F9D72BD812540F0604AC4F26B46404C4BAE918A8125400B0883BFD46B46406072CEC9B08025402D8F11D7E16B4640A9473320E5802540E197733EFF6B4640 |
| 1 |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|
| 1 | 0103000020E6100000010000000C0000001C0A86C0438125404189C67D516D4640A12D26DA4F812540747A21C1556D46404A89CDC65E8125403808965E5B6D46401EFA988123822540EA6FF1E03F6D46406014914C22822540097BFD7D3F6D46403D69CAC2DF812540C302E9DF426D4640DBA2A4F4A18125407EA0B3B6476D4640128FB7508D81254058C05754496D46406BC430498D812540F49E7255496D4640BCF34C126F812540ECF280B24B6D464090173FC643812540E753A87E516D46401C0A86C0438125404189C67D516D4640 |
| 1 | 0103000020E6100000010000000C0000001C0A86C0438125404189C67D516D4640A12D26DA4F812540747A21C1556D46404A89CDC65E8125403808965E5B6D46401EFA988123822540EA6FF1E03F6D46406014914C22822540097BFD7D3F6D46403D69CAC2DF812540C302E9DF426D4640DBA2A4F4A18125407EA0B3B6476D4640128FB7508D81254058C05754496D46406BC430498D812540F49E7255496D4640BCF34C126F812540ECF280B24B6D464090173FC643812540E753A87E516D46401C0A86C0438125404189C67D516D4640 |

and this is the query I'm using to get clusters

```
select inte1, ST_ConcaveHull(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(geom_pol, (100 / 111111.0))), 1) as geom
from example
group by inte1
```

With `target_percent=1` the query completes successfully (2 clusters found).
I wanted a more accurate result so I tried decreasing `target_percent`. I tried with `target_percent=0.9/0.8/0.7` ecc. and the query gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  lwpoly_from_lwlines: shell must have at least 4 points
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_concavehull(geometry,double precision,boolean) line 144 at assignment
SQL state: XX000
```

How can i solve this error?

PostGIS version: `"2.5 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1"`

PostgreSQL version: `"PostgreSQL 11.11, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit"`

Comment: Upgrade Postgis. With version 3, your sample data works fine with any percentage